# NPM install hanging when installing pouchDB

Tags: node.js, npm, pouchdb

I have been trying to install pouchdb for 2 days now.

I have tried re-installing node. I have tried re-installing python. I have scoured stack overflow and the rest of the interwebz.

The install (`sudo npm install puchdb`) just hangs on here:

```
> leveldown@0.9.2 install /Users/myUser/Sites/sen-proj/qti-test/node_modules/pouchdb/node_modules/level/node_modules/leveldown
> node-gyp rebuild
```

When I run `sudo npm install pouchdb --verbose` I get:

```
npm info linkStuff level-packager@0.17.0-5
npm verb linkBins level-packager@0.17.0-5
npm verb linkMans level-packager@0.17.0-5
npm verb rebuildBundles level-packager@0.17.0-5
npm verb rebuildBundles [ 'levelup' ]
npm info install level-packager@0.17.0-5
npm info postinstall level-packager@0.17.0-5
```

Any ideas?

I was running on Mountain Lion. In hopes of fixing this I upgraded to Mavericks. I will keep people posted. Of course now that I have Mavericks get isn't working. Getting xcode... Again.

Comment: It might be possible to work around the issue by specifying an earlier version e.g. `npm install pouchdb@<version>`. Also, specifying the platform you're using could help others answer the question.

Comment: What version of node? of npm? Have you tried `git clone`-ing the [pouchdb repo on github](https://github.com/daleharvey/pouchdb/) and running `npm install` inside of it?

Answer (score 0):

try doing `rm -rf node_moudules` and then reinstalling, this is an issue with [leveldown](https://github.com/rvagg/node-leveldown) so googling for that might be easier.